# A way to sum supernatural numbers involving Zeta function's analytic continuation

Tags: prime-numbers, field-theory, riemann-zeta, infinite-product

I have this idea on how to sum supernatural numbers assigning them a finite value in a way similar to how we assume that the sum of every natural numbers from 1 to infinity equals $-\frac 1 {12}$.
Let's take for example the number: $\omega_2=\prod_{n=1}^\infty2$

Which can be written as: $\omega_2=2\times2\times2\times\dots$

And with basics power properties we can rewrite it as: $\omega_2=2^{1+1+1+\dots}$

Now recalling Riemann's Zeta function and it's analytic continuation we have:

$\omega_2=2^{\zeta(0)}=2^{-\frac 1 2}={\sqrt2\over2}$

We can extend this to every number of the form: $\omega_s=\prod_{n=1}^\infty s={\sqrt s\over s}$
where $s$ is prime.

We can easily now sum supernatural numbers, for example:

$\omega_2+\omega_3=2\times2\times2\times\dots+3\times3\times3\times\dots={3\sqrt2+2\sqrt3\over 6}$

Did I made something wrong ? Is this useful in some ways ?

Comment: But if $s=6$ or $s=12$ you get the same supernatural number product of $2^{\infty}3^{\infty}$ but $\frac{\sqrt{6}}{6}\neq \frac{\sqrt{12}}{12}$.

Comment: I'm guessing not at all useful, but who knows.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews my bad I've been too general in my explanation, I edit it now. $s$ must be prime.

Comment: Why isn't $2^{\infty}=2^{1}\cdot 2^{2}\cdot 2^{3}\cdots = 2^{\zeta(-1)}$, for example? Basically, either $1+1+1+\cdots=\infty$ or it is $-1/2$. You can't have it both ways. That is why this nonsense about $1+2+3\cdots=-1/12$ is so damaging to good mathematics.

Comment: Because the definition of a supernatural number is $p\times p\times p\times\dots$ and not $p\times p^2\times p^3\times\dots$

Comment: It's probably not more useful than just considering the field extension of $\mathbb Q$ generated by square roots; they do a really lousy job representing infinite products since, for some reason, with this, we have $2\times \omega_2 \neq \omega_2$, even though either side looks like an identical infinite product.

Comment: Or maybe I got this wrong and here's the point @ThomasAndrews

Comment: @RenatoFaraone No, that is not the definition of Supernatural number.

Comment: Specifically, $2^{\infty}\cdot 2^{\infty}=2^{\infty}$, which is going to render interpreting  supernatural numbers as a bit silly.

Comment: This whole $\zeta(-1)$ stuff that has been popularized leads you up a wrong path. It is like trying to learn about human nature by reading "Ripley's Believe It Or Not" - the things that are true in it are buried amongst a lot of simplifications and falsehoods.

Comment: I know @ThomasAndrews, I'm just wondering where can I apply this kind of math tricks and where I cannot.

Comment: Don't try to apply it at all. Really, just don't. It's bad math. @RenatoFaraone And, no, apparently, you don't know.

Comment: We know that $N \subset N_s$. A binary operation $+_s:N_s\times N_s \to N_s$ is called a generalized sum operation if  

(i) $n +_s m= n+m $ for each $n,m \in N$;

(ii) $s_1 +_s s_2= s_2 +_s s_1$ for each $s_1,s_2 \in N_s$;

(iii) $s_1(s_2+_s s_3)=s_1s_2 +_s s_1s_3$ for each  $s_1,s_2,s_3 \in N_s$;

(iv) $(s_2+_s s_3)s_1=s_2s_1 +_s s_3s_1$ for each  $s_1,s_2,s_3 \in N_s$;The problem is whether we can define GSO on $N_s$.